# Markup language instead of HTML

Tags: python, html, markdown, markup

I'm building a website, but don't want to write any HTML (or XML). I was thinking that I could use a nicer markup language instead.

I've looked at *Markdown* and *reStructuredText*, but they don't support all the HTML "features" I need. Are there any markup languages that I could use instead of writing a lot of intricate HTML, or do I need to invent something myself? (I'm looking for something available in *Python*)

**EDIT**

I want to create arbitrary HTML structures with arbitrary content (nesting, random attributes, etc.). Also a simple readable syntax for tables would be nice.

Under the term niceness I mean: I want it to be more human readable (less crud) and less verbose (less typing). Indenting instead of manually closing tags would be nice.

**EDIT2**

I wasn't looking to replace HTML: I just wanted to write something else and then convert to it at runtime.

Comment: Niceness is a subjective concept, and we don't know what features you need.

Comment: What specific features are you after? You say HTML is too much and Markdown is too little - where's your happy medium?

Comment: What features are Markdown and reStructuredText lacking that you need?

Comment: I hope you brought your flamesuit.

Comment: Yes, definitely. You should invent something yourself. Make sure Microsoft, Google, and Mozilla know ahead of time. They need time to adapt to your new language. ;)

Comment: By the time you develop, test and implement your 'HTML alternative' I'll have banged out countless sites using HTML.  Not to mention you'll have no clue whether or not the user's browser supports your new, proprietary markup.  Also, good luck getting common HTML parsers or JS to work with your made-up solution.

Comment: If you really don't want to touch HTML (which is kind of a silly fear), then use a WYSIWYG editor like DreamWeaver. What do you have against HTML?

Comment: Why is there so much hate here? Perfectly valid question, perhaps a bit poorly worded.

Comment: Jani Hartikainen: Thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there aren't really many alternatives for writing actual website structural markup in other languages than HTML.

The only thing that I've heard of is [Haml, HTML Abstraction Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haml). It's a short and concise markup language which translates directly into HTML markup, so perhaps it's worth a look?

The only other option I can think of is using some sort of monstrous hybrid of XSLT and HTML, which I don't think is any  good at all except for making your brain hurt.

Comment: `I'm building a website, but don't want to write any HTML (or XML).`  I think XSLT is out of the question here, @Jani

Comment: @George yeah I only mentioned it because it's the only other alternative besides Haml that I could think of :)

Comment: I've heard of Haml, never looked into it though. Looks great, maybe it's just the thing I need. Thanks!

Comment: If someone else is interested: through Haml I found markaby, which is pretty interesting (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markaby)

Answer (score 0):

You can't build a *working* website without HTML, seeing as the implementation isn't inside browsers like Firefox, Chrome, etc. Markdown and reStructuredText are simply markup syntax processors (just like BBCode for example).

Now on to the other good stuff. If you want to build a dynamic website using Python, you can use [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) (which is a Python web framework). The [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/) should also help you out a lot, in conjunction with the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/).

Django DOES have a templating system which does make HTML coding nicer (TONS nicer) however.

To learn HTML and JS, I suggest using [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/). Warning though! Some of their information IS incomplete and inaccurate (see [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/) for this).